# Sizing fonts and fallback fonts differently?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, responsive-emails

I'm using typekit to bring in a font for my email. Obviously this does not work on all clients so I have a fallback.

How can I specify font sizes and other styles for my typekit font and my fallback font? As the typekit font is slightly larger to begin with i want to size it differently.

Comment: What you need is `font-size-adjust`, unfortunately it's not super widely supported as yet. If full support across the board right now is necessary, you'll have to go with a JavaScript option.

Comment: No javascript in emails.

Comment: Ah, did see it was for an email. In which case you're probably out of luck - any client which has support for font-size-adjust likely supports your custom font anyway, so that's no help.

Comment: Well thanks anyway - I did not know about font size adjust so something learnt!